# Issues with Python thread pool

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm having a trouble using python to write a website spider. The basic idea is as follows:

I have a queue, and each thread gets a url from the queue and calls a function `getAllLinks` to get links from that url. Pseudocode as follows:

```
class Spider(Threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = Queue.Queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            url = self.queue.get()
            getAllLinks(url)  
            time.sleep(0.1)   #I try to release the GIL
```

But the problem is: even though I switch threads manually after calling getAllLinks, the program is not as fast as a single-threaded one. Is there a better way?

I want using multiple threads to increase the spider's processing speed, but I think `time.sleep()` is slower, because I force a thread to release the GIL.

I think this is similar to: `for url in urlList: spider(url)`. Isn't switching threads only after `getAllLinks()`, essentially the same as just using one thread?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `time.sleep()` statement?  Obviously that will introduce a delay, but presumably you have a reason?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, can you restate it?

Comment: So, basically, when you run the solution with multiple threads, it is not as fast as running it on a single thread? And you would like suggestions on how to make multi-threading work to increase speed performance for this application? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

So, your multithreaded program is not significantly faster than a single-threaded version of it.

You're correct in that the CPython interpreter will release the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), [every 100 byte codes](http://poshmodule.sourceforge.net/posh/html/node1.html). Unfortunately, the GIL makes multithreaded programs that don't extensively use I/O useless:

> Does the GIL block those peo­ple who are work­ing in pure Python from truly tak­ing advan­tage of mul­ti­ple cores? Sim­ply put: Yes, it does. While threads them­selves are a lan­guage con­struct, the inter­preter is the gate­keeper to the map­ping between threads and the OS. ([source](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/01/python-threads-and-the-global-interpreter-lock/)).

But, you say you're extensively using I/O. The GIL is released when I/O is done, meaning your program *could* see speed results using multithreading.

So, post the code to your `getAllLinks` function! That way we can benchmark what's working and what's not working. And, though you can use `time.sleep(.0001)` to trick the GIL into releasing (use a smaller number than `0.1`), since you're using a lot of I/O you shouldn't need this hack. Remove that line.

Comment: The geAllLinks code as follows:


def getAllLinks(url):
 import urllib2 as urllib
 sock = urllib.urlopen(url)
 htmlCode = sock.read()
 ....
 sock.close()

Comment: Why are you creating a new Queue.Queue in each Spider class?